# Rollup - incorrect path resolution

Tags: node.js, path, relative-path, rollupjs

I want to use the library `ebnf` from NPM and create a bundle using `rollup`. Since the `ebnf` is installed to `node_modules` I also use the rollup plugin `rollup-plugin-node-resolve`.

The problem is that `ebnf` contains the code `require('..')` which - in my case - is resolved to `dist` in my case. Thus it seems `..` is interpreted relative to the output file instead of being relative to the source file.

This is my `rollup.config.js` (taken from my test repo [jneuendorf/rollup-broken-resolve](https://github.com/jneuendorf/rollup-broken-resolve)):

```
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs'


export default {
    input: 'src/index.js',
    output: {
        file: 'dist/bundle.js',
        format: 'cjs'
    },
    // name: 'MyModule',
    plugins: [
        resolve(),
        commonjs(),
    ]
}
```

Is this a problem in `rollup-plugin-node-resolve` or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar problem as well - rollup-plugin-node-resolve is adding a `require('../myutilsfile.js')` in the bundle which is causing the consumers of the bundled module to throw "cannot resolve '../myutilsfile.js'". Any luck on this?

Answer (score 1):

Since some of the external libraries needed will still be available only as Common.js modules, you could also convert them to ES-Modules:

> "Since most packages in your node_modules folder are probably legacy CommonJS rather than JavaScript modules, you may need to use rollup-plugin-commonjs"

- **https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs**

  *"Convert CommonJS modules to ES6, so they can be included in a Rollup bundle"*

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone searching this issue on how to make `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve` (previously was `rollup-plugin-node-resolve`) to work with relative path. I just found [the solution](https://github.com/taufik-nurrohman/factory/blob/v2.0.6/index.mjs#L114-L131):

```js
function resolve(file, origin) {
    // Your way to resolve local include path
}

function pathResolve(options) {
    return {
        resolveId: function(file, origin) {
            // Your local include path must either starts with `./` or `../`
            if (file.startsWith('./') || file.startsWith('../')) {
                // Return an absolute include path
                return resolve(file, origin);
            }
            return null; // Continue to the next plugins!
        }
    };
}
```

Here is how to combine it with `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve`:

```js
import {nodeResolve} from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';

function pathResolve(options) { /* ... */ }

export default {
  // ...
  plugins: [pathResolve(), nodeResolve()]
};
```